# How can i make a LinQ query using where and with an int[] list?

Tags: c#, linq

Im just starting to learn how to use LinQ,
I want to only show grades that are 9 and 10 from a list i have but when trying to use var and foreach it wont let me, not sure why.

This is the list i was provided:

```
int[] grades= { 5, 9, 7, 8, 6, 9, 5, 7, 7, 4, 6, 10, 8 };
```

And here im trying to do the query:

```
        var grades1 = from s in grades
        where s.grades>= 9 
        select s;

        foreach (var cal in grades)
        Console.WriteLine(cal.grades);
```

The thing is that it shows an error when doing s.grades and cal.grades. I cant change the int[]grades.

Comment: Can you please share the error you are getting?

Comment: try cal.grades.ToString();

Comment: You're assigning to `grades1` and then using `grades`

Comment: The variable `s` represents an element of `grades`. Since `grades` is an `int[]`, `s` is an `int`. So it needs to be `where s >= 9`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
int[] grades = { 5, 9, 7, 8, 6, 9, 5, 7, 7, 4, 6, 10, 8 };
var grades1 = from s in grades
              where s >= 9
              select s;

foreach (var cal in grades1)
    Console.WriteLine(cal);
```

`s` is an `int` so you can't qualify it. You are selecting an `int` element of an array of ints

Comment: Thank you so much this helped alot! As you said the problem was with the int element

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 int[] grades = { 5, 9, 7, 8, 6, 9, 5, 7, 7, 4, 6, 10, 8 };

var grades1 = from s in grades
              where s >= 9
              select s;

foreach (var cal in grades1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(cal);

}
```